# Customized error message for deleted function use

Tags: c++, attributes, compiler-warnings, noncopyable

Let's say I have a noncopyable class and I want to provide a customized error message when users try to copy.

```
struct A {
    A() = default;

private:
    [[deprecated("customized message")]]
    A(const A&);

    [[deprecated("customized message")]]
    A& operator=(const A&);
};
```

I cannot use =delete for them, because compiler would only complain they are deleted.
So I tried the transitional way: private non-defined functions.

Compiler will show

```
warning: 'A::A(const A&)' is deprecated: customized message [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

It works but not that good, because the word *deprecated* sounds like allowed-but-discouraged rather than disallowed simply.

My another try is

```
struct Customized_Message {
    Customized_Message() = default;
    Customized_Message(const Customized_Message&) = delete;
    Customized_Message& operator=(const Customized_Message&) = delete;
};
struct A : Customized_Message {
    A() = default;
};
```

```
<source>:17:11: error: use of deleted function 'A::A(const A&)'
   17 |     A b = a;
      |           ^
<source>:11:8: note: 'A::A(const A&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   11 | struct A : Customized_Message {
      |        ^
<source>:11:8: error: use of deleted function 'Customized_Message::Customized_Message(const Customized_Message&)'
<source>:8:5: note: declared here
    8 |     Customized_Message(const Customized_Message&) = delete;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It works but looks not elegant ([Edit] because the message is not short, and compiler will replicate it as above).

Is there a better way to provide a customized error message? Thank you.

Comment: is it some class specific text or just something along the line of "this class cannot be copied" ?

Comment: btw "elegant" is purely subjective. Your second appraoch is similar to `boost::non_copyable`. It is widely used hence cannot be too bad

Comment: Might your custom error message be more confusing then the standard error message the compiler emits which developers are already familiar with ?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the customized message would be something like "XXX is disallowed, please use YYY, detailed documentation is in ZZZ."

Comment: its not clear why you think it is "not elegant". Is it because you have to write a class to be inherited from? Is it because you have to write another class for a different custom message? How about having a member named `XXX_is_disallowed_please_use_YYY_detailed_documentation_is_in_ZZZ` that is not copyable?

Comment: If it's non-defined, compiler might go on but linker will complain, so I don't see the point there. Besides that, your approach #2 is understandable I think.

Comment: well, more seriously, you cannot solve the issue of a user not reading documentation with this one instance of a compiler error message a user gets when they do something wrong. And you should not. A user is used to their compilers error messages, and they should have read documentation before writing the wrong code. Reality is that this wont be the case always, but you cannot solve that by turning a well readable and clear error message into a custom one

Comment: take a look at `boost::non_copyable`, though afaik this predates `= delete` (which you should prefer to declare but not define, a compiler error is already so much clearer than a linker error)

Comment: fwiw, I think this question is missing details, because it cannot be answered without knowing what you consider as "elegant" or "better", hence my vote to close. When you have a solution and you do not like it you need to explain why you don't like it rather than assume that it is obvious, it isnt.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it.

Comment: How to close a question?